# Error No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of SqlDataReader,String,Object)'.- Inline function

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have got this error
`No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of SqlDataReader,String,Object)'.`

My Code is below

`dsBranch.Tables.Add(GetDataTableFromSQLReader(dr, ""))` - Calling

```
Private Function GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader(ByVal dr As SqlDataReader, ByVal TableName As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable(TableName)
    dt.Load(dr)
    Return dt
End Function
Dim GetDataTableFromSQLReader = Function(dr As SqlDataReader, TableName As String) GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader(dr, TableName)
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class NoDefaultMemberFoundError

    ' Added "As DataTable"
    Private Function GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader(ByVal dr As SqlDataReader, _
                                                   ByVal TableName As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable(TableName)
        dt.Load(dr)
        Return dt
    End Function

    ' This is how it has to be declared
    Dim GetDataTableFromSQLReader As Func(Of SqlDataReader, String, DataTable) = _
                       Function(dr, TableName) GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader(dr, TableName)

    Sub Test()
        Dim dsBranch As DataSet = Nothing
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing

        dsBranch.Tables.Add(GetDataTableFromSQLReader(dr, ""))
    End Sub
End Class
```

You should set the `Option Strict` to `On`. It would help you to declare the correct types. For instance, your Function had no return type declared. This was probably the main source of the error.

Your Lambda assignment was also not correct. Lambda expressions always have to be assigned to a concrete type. This enables the compiler to infer their exact signature.

---

EDIT (explanation of delegates and lambda expressions):

With

```
Dim GetDataTableFromSQLReader As Func(Of SqlDataReader, String, DataTable)
```

you define a variable, which can hold a function, or more precisely its address, in a specialized class called a 'delegate'. In terms of .NET this variable is a delegate which refers to a method (unless it is `Nothing`). According to the declaration above, this function must accept one parameter of type `SqlDataReader` and one of type `String`. The return value must be of type `DataTable`.

You can assign any function, which has this requested signature to the variable:

```
GetDataTableFromSQLReader = AddressOf GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader
```

is a valid assignment. (I could have simplified the example in my original answer this way.) Now you can use the variable as if it was a function:

```
Dim DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromSQLReader(dr, "")
```

In reality this calls the function that was assigned to it, namely `GetDataTableFromSQLDataReader`. This makes sense, if we want to get the data tables in different ways. We could assign another function, say `GetDataTableInADifferentWay` to our variable. The call `GetDataTableFromSQLReader(dr, "")` would then call this other function without the need of having an If-Then-Else-statement when we call it.

Now, to the lambda expressions with a detour over delegates. Let us take an example that is more suitable. We want to print a table with function values:

```
Public Sub PrintFunction()
    For Dim x As Double = 1 To 10
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, f(x) = {1}", x, x*x)
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can see, we print the squares of 1 to 10. However, what about printing other functions? We would have to change our `PrintFunction` each time we need to print another function. Here delegates come into the game. Let us change the declaration to

```
Public Sub PrintFunction(Func(Of Double, Double) f)
    For Dim x As Double = 1 To 10
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, f(x) = {1}", x, f(x))
    Next
End Sub
```

Now let us declare a square function and a reciprocal function

```
Public Function Square(x As Double) As Double
    Return x*x
End Function

Public Function Reciprocal(x As Double) As Double
    Return 1 / x
End Function
```

Now we can print two different value tables with

```
PrintFunction(AddressOf Square)
PrintFunction(AddressOf Reciprocal)
```

We have not used lambda expressions yet. They are simply a very concise way of declaring delegates (or functions, if you prefer) on the fly. Instead of declaring a square and a reciprocal function, we can print the tables like this:

```
PrintFunction(Function(x) x*x)
PrintFunction(Function(x) 1 / x)
```

Comment: @Oliver . Thanks . i m new to lamda expression, can you provide some more details ?

Comment: I added a short explanation for delegates and lambda expressions. See [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) on MSDN for more information.